# I'm getting an overflow error in my code but i can't seem to fix it, any suggestions?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

here is the code i am working with

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Main{

  public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;

    System.out.println("please enter the first string"); 

    String q = scan.nextLine ();
    int b = q.length();
    int asterisk = q.indexOf('*');

    while(c < b-1)
    {
      c++;
      if (q.charAt(c) == '*')
      {
        d++;
        break;
      }
    }

    if(d<1)
    {
      System.out.println("Error: no *");
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("Enter the replacement string");
    }
    String rep = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println(q.substring(0,q.indexOf('*')) + rep + q.substring(asterisk+1,b)); 

  }

 }
```

and the error i am receiving

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:

  String index out of range: 22

  at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)

  at Main.main(Main.java:282)

  at Ideone.assertRegex(Main.java:125)
  at Ideone.test(Main.java:45)
  at Ideone.main(Main.java:28)
```

I'm thinking this has something to do with the charAt i'm using, though i can't properly figure out how to correct this issue
I'm rather new to coding so it's possible that there is some easy fix i'm overlooking
if anyone can help out it would be appreciated

Comment: I like how the StackTrace says the error is at line 282 but your code is not even near that long.

Comment: Your formatting is also pretty horrible.  Can you fix the indent and the braces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you increment c before calling charAt, effectively getting out of range, in the last char. You must increment c after calling charAt. You must also compare with b not b-1, so you won't miss the last character.

So replace this

```
while(c < b-1) {
   c++;
   if (q.charAt(c) == '*') { 
      d++;
      break;
   }
}
```

with this:

```
while(c < b) {
   if (q.charAt(c) == '*') { 
      d++;
      break;
   }
   c++;
}
```

Comment: After applying your fix i get a different outofboundsexception error:


Exception in thread "main" 

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
 at Main.main(Main.java:293)
 at Ideone.assertRegex(Main.java:125)
 at Ideone.test(Main.java:51)
 at Ideone.main(Main.java:28)